# If variable matches 3 conditions

Tags: javascript

I need to have an if statement to check if a number is = 0, or between 5000 and 3600000. How can have it check all 3 conditions?

Number can be 0 or 5000 or above OR 3600000 or less. It can't be -1, 1.1 2.3 or anything between 0 and 5.

Here is what I have now and this work for checking if less than 5000 or greater than 3600000

```
var intervalCheck = interval * digit
if(isNaN(intervalCheck))
{
    alert("Must be a number.");
}
else if((intervalCheck < 5000)||(intervalCheck>=3600000))
{
    alert("Must be between 5 seconds and 1 hour.");
}
else
{
    localStorage["interval_setting"] = interval * digit;
    saveActions();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((intervalCheck == 0) || (intervalCheck >= 5000 && intervalCheck <= 3600000)) {
    // put your code here
}
```

You can combine as many logic operations as you want into one `if` statement using any of the javascript logic and comparision operators.

You can see a demo work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y5tRK/

Comment: Sorry to say but none of these solution work. These solution allow numbers less than 0 or 1,2,3,4. I need the opposite of that. If 0 good or if 5000 or greater but less than 3600000

Comment: @AlexOulapour - I think you don't understand the compound logic here.  This requires that intervalCheck be BOTH >= 5000 AND <= 3600000.  Numbers like 1,2,3,4 won't pass this test.

Comment: I'm testing it right now and 1,2,3,4 are the only numbers that pass.

Comment: It's setting a timer. The values can be 0 (off) or 5 seconds to 1 hour.

Comment: @AlexOulapour - you can see a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y5tRK where you can test any value you want.  It does what you asked for.  Perhaps we need to see the whole body of code you're running.

Comment: I see what I did. I was using this statement to check for the fail condition not the success. It's working now. Thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if(intervalCheck === 0 || (intervalCheck >= 5000 && intervalCheck <= 3600000)) {
  localStorage["interval_setting"] = interval * digit;
  saveActions();
}
else {
   alert('You broke something");
}
```

The `===` means to check both type and value.  This makes sure that intervalCheck is both a number and equal to zero, instead of evaluating to true if intervalCheck is `""` or `false`.  Then we  give our `or` condition. We wrap this in parenthesis becuase we need to ensure that the value falls between our two  numbers.  The parenthesis mean this will be evaluated as a whole with the `or`.

Comment: Sorry to say but none of these solution work. These solution allow numbers less than 0 or 1,2,3,4. I need the opposite of that. If 0 good or if 5000 or greater but less than 3600000

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have an if statement to check if a number is = 0, or between
>   5000 and 3600000.

```
if( intervalCheck == 0 || (intervalCheck >= 5000 && intervalCheck <= 3600000) ) {
   //code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say but none of these solution work. These solution allow numbers less than 0 or 1,2,3,4. I need the opposite of that. If 0 good or if 5000 or greater but less than 3600000

Answer (score 0):

```
if(intervalCheck == 0 || (intervalCheck >= 5000 && intervalCheck<=3600000))
```

Comment: Sorry to say but none of these solution work. These solution allow numbers less than 0 or 1,2,3,4. I need the opposite of that. If 0 good or if 5000 or greater but less than 3600000

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isNaN(intervalCheck) && (intervalCheck == 0 || (intervalCheck >= 5000 && intervalCheck <= 3600000)))
```